# How to use javascript to hide things

Tags: javascript, menu, responsive-design

I have one problem. I am making (wordpress) onepage website and my mobile menu is not hiding when I click on anchor. I need help with creating next javascript code:
When click on  hide ... And there is also class for  when it's closed . Thank you in advance :D

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: share your effort with us. show code that we can work with for helping.

Comment: you can read some tutorial first like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Comment: As I said bellow, I tried to use a lot of different stuff,tutorials, etc. nothing helped.. since I am not an expert for java, I reached here for help. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation col-md-8" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu-menu-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-177"><a href="xxx">HOME</a></li>
```

ABOUT
PORTOFOLIO
PROJECTS
CONTACT
LOGIN PAGE
         
            HOME
ABOUT
PORTOFOLIO
PROJECTS
CONTACT
LOGIN PAGE

```
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I searched google hundred times and try milions of stuff so pls if you can help me it'd be great